# Ubuntu not using/detecting full drive

Tags: partitioning, drive

I upgraded my drive from a 1TB to a 2TB a while back.

However, today when I tried to do something, it said I was out of space.
When I check the home folder, I see this:

https://i.gyazo.com/0dcd3a19db592597f95161d925845211.png

Ubuntu seems to think I only have 1TB of space.

At first, I thought maybe I made a mistake when expanding the partition, but the disks menu shows the partition as 2TB:

https://i.gyazo.com/bb0a270f40988efc5ba75f0d8530009e.png

Anyone know why my Block Device is only using 1TB still?

Comment: You're using a LVM partition which the second image shows.  PV = physical volume; but 'pv' doesn't show how it is located (which is in logical-volumes).  Maybe another user can help with GUI tools for lvm, but I only manage them at terminal, so I'd suggest using the commands `lvdisplay` to display your logical-volumes where the field you're interested in is "LV Size" (logical volume size).  LVM allows you to change it anytime, increase just by adding extra drives; shrink by removing drives (as long as space isn't being used) etc. You may not have allocated all the space.

Comment: How do I allocate the space?